# Delphi Indy 10 HTTPServer bind database instance to session

Tags: database, delphi, session, indy

Is there any best practice to bind database connection instances to INDY HTTP Server sessions?

I store usual session data in `ARequestInfo.Session.Content.Values` but this is only for strings. My current approach for database objects is (`TDatabase`is just an example class):

- Create a `TDictionary<String,TDatabase>`.
- Create `TDatabase` instances for every session and store references along with the session id in the dictionary.
- Access the dictionary enclosed in critical sections within the session processing to be thread safe.
- Destroy `TDatabase` instances when sessions are destroyed.

I suspect that my approach is overhead and there are much more elegant ways to achieve what I want. If this is the case - Tips are very welcome.

Comment: Why do you need a new TDatabase instance for each connection?

Comment: I create an independant database session for each session for several reasons. I need to use transactions, the access rights to the database depend on the user of the session and I trace changes to the database in triggers depending on the user (audit trail).

Comment: I still can't see the reason why you need to store DB connection in session. Is connecting to DB upon each request an issue? Then you should use connection pooling. Do you maintain a transaction across several requests? That would be a terrible solution to a problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Transactions are short and never span across reqiests. But as I set several(Firebird) Environment vars that are used within triggers and different database users are used due to security a dedicated connection per session is required and a connection pool would not help very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Session.Content` property is a `TStrings`, which can hold strings AND `TObject` pointers. You don't need a separate `TDictionary` to map strings to objects, you can store them together in the `Content` itself.

Alternatively, you can derive a new class from `TIdHTTPSession`, add your database connection to that class, and then use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCreateSession` event to create instances of that class.  Then, to access the database connection, simply typecast any `TIdHTTPSession` object to your class type.

Comment: Thanks, That's the way I will do it.